# Angular9 http.get() doesn´t work properly

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, https, httpclient

i'm developing a simple app to make consults to a backend on NodeJS. Everything works perfectly on localhost, but when i run the angular server on my ip adress (192.168.1.x) it dosen`t work anymore.
The nodeJS REST api it's running on 'http://localhost:3000/api/article' and the Angular server in https://192.168.1.x:4200.
The http.get code its this:

articles.component.ts:

```
import {ArticlesService} from '../../services/articles.service';
import {Article} from '../../models/article';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.scss'],
  providers: [ArticlesService],
  
})

export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public articlesService: ArticlesService) { }

  article: Article;

  //Some other code that dosen't afect this

  getArticle(id: String) {
    this.articlesService.getArticle(id)
    .subscribe( res => {
      this.article = res as Article;
    })
  }
```

articles.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticlesService {

  readonly API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api/article';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }
  getArticle(id: String) {
      return this.http.get(this.API_URI+`/${id}`);
  }
}
```

I`ve been trying some flags test and i realize that it never enter on the subscribe(), i'm new and it's the first time i run the server on my current ip and not in the localhost. So, i don't if maybe i can't request at the backend like that in this case or something else.

Using morgan and postman at the nodeJS REST api i see that the get request work properly on that side.

If someone could help me it would be awsome.

Comment: if you get no response then that means that is not hitting the endpoint, which means something's not right with your api route (this points to the resource not existing or the api route is wrong). It could also be that the port is being used by a different resource, check the network tab in your dev tools and see the response.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly don't get you with the Angular server but all indicates that your Angular server doesn't have visibility of your localhost:3000. It's like when you deploy your spa in another server. That server doesnt know about your localhost and you have to replace your `API_URI` (using environments.ts) with the IP or domain name where your backend is:

For example i have this in my environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    apiUrl: 'https://urltothenodejsbackend/api',
    apiVersion: '/v1'
};
```

Comment: I tried it and still doesn't work, my Nodejs backend it's running on http, and Angular on https. Could it be a problem?